# What models are available to estimate effect of surface water on groundwater quality?

Tags: models, groundwater

I want to determine the effect of surface water quality or the effect of chemicals used on surface like fertilizers on groundwater. What choices do I have for predicting groundwater quality? What are pros and cons of different available models? The model/models should particularly be able to simulate behaviour of pollutants in unsaturated zone!

Comment: Which models do you know already? Which research on these models did you perform prior to asking this question?

Comment: So far I came to know about only HP1 model, which simulates fate of chemicals in unsaturate zone, coupling richard's equation with PhreeqC. MT3D which comes with MODFLOW is for saturated flow.